# Pandas: Get Business Month-End Dates Correctly Even for Dates Already on Month-End

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

let's say i have and dataframe as below

```
date,ent_id,val
2021-03-23,101,61
2021-03-12,103,64
2021-03-15,101,32
2021-04-01,103,39
2021-04-02,101,71
2021-04-02,103,79
2021-04-30,101,51
2021-04-30,103,53
2021-05-31,101,28
2021-05-31,103,26
2021-05-31,101,47
2021-05-31,103,61
2021-06-06,101,45
2021-06-06,103,78
2021-06-07,101,23
2021-06-07,103,31
2021-07-31,101,14
2021-07-31,103,02
2021-07-31,101,82
2021-07-31,103,15
```

i want to create an addition column in dataframe which contain month end date
based of following condition

```
case 
when DAYNAME('date')='Sunday' then days_add(date,-2)
when DAYNAME('date')='Saturday' then days_add(date,-1)
else date
```

so the output would be like this

```
date,ent_id,val,month_end
2021-03-23,101,61,2021-03-31
2021-03-12,103,64,2021-03-31
2021-03-15,101,32,2021-03-31
2021-04-01,103,39,2021-04-30
2021-04-02,101,71,2021-04-30
2021-04-02,103,79,2021-04-30
2021-04-30,101,51,2021-04-30
2021-04-30,103,53,2021-04-30
2021-05-31,101,28,2021-05-31
2021-05-31,103,26,2021-05-31
2021-05-31,101,47,2021-05-31
2021-05-31,103,61,2021-05-31
2021-06-06,101,45,2021-06-30
2021-06-06,103,78,2021-06-30
2021-06-07,101,23,2021-06-30
2021-06-07,103,31,2021-06-30
2021-07-31,101,14,2021-07-31
2021-07-31,103,02,2021-07-31
2021-07-31,101,82,2021-07-31
2021-07-31,103,15,2021-07-31
```

my effort

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
import numpy as np

df.loc[(df['date']+MonthEnd(0)).dt.day_name()=='Sunday','month_end'] =[df.loc[(df['date']+MonthEnd(0)).dt.day_name()=='Sunday']['date']+timedelta(days=-2)]
df.loc[(df['date']+MonthEnd(0)).dt.day_name()=='Saturday','month_end'] =[df.loc[(df['date']+MonthEnd(0)).dt.day_name()=='Saturday']['date']+timedelta(days=-1)]
```

but getting this error

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
```

any other better solution is most welcome

Comment: See my edit that makes use only of the Pandas date offset functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html?highlight=monthend#anchored-offset-semantics) and then adjust for Sunday and Saturday.  Note that `n=0` is needed or else 2021-07-31 will be rolled forward to 2021-08-31.

```
df['month_end'] = df['date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0)
df.loc[df['month_end'].dt.day_name() == 'Sunday', 'month_end'] -= pd.DateOffset(2)
df.loc[df['month_end'].dt.day_name() == 'Saturday', 'month_end'] -= pd.DateOffset(1)


print(df)

         date  ent_id  val  month_end
0  2021-03-23     101   61 2021-03-31
1  2021-03-12     103   64 2021-03-31
2  2021-03-15     101   32 2021-03-31
3  2021-04-01     103   39 2021-04-30
4  2021-04-02     101   71 2021-04-30
5  2021-04-02     103   79 2021-04-30
6  2021-04-30     101   51 2021-04-30
7  2021-04-30     103   53 2021-04-30
8  2021-05-31     101   28 2021-05-31
9  2021-05-31     103   26 2021-05-31
10 2021-05-31     101   47 2021-05-31
11 2021-05-31     103   61 2021-05-31
12 2021-06-06     101   45 2021-06-30
13 2021-06-06     103   78 2021-06-30
14 2021-06-07     101   23 2021-06-30
15 2021-06-07     103   31 2021-06-30
16 2021-07-31     101   14 2021-07-30
17 2021-07-31     103    2 2021-07-30
18 2021-07-31     101   82 2021-07-30
19 2021-07-31     103   15 2021-07-30
```

Note that although you seems to want to get the last business date of a month, we **cannot simply use `pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(n=0)`** since 2021-07-31 will still be rolled forward to 2021-08-31.

### Edit: Solution using BMonthEnd

When I first looked at the question, what immediately popped up to my mind is that probably we can make use of `pd.offsets.BMonthEnd` to solve the question.

As I also know that for `pd.offsets.MonthEnd`, we can use parameter `n=0` (or simply `0`) to ensure the date is not rolled if on an anchor point (on an anchor point if the date is already on month-end date in this case).  Hence, my initial trial is to use `pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(n=0)`.  To my surprise, it doesn't behave similarly as the MonthEnd counterpart.  Date of `2021-07-31` is still rolled forward to `2021-08-31`.

As this kind of problem is very common, I would like to provide a workaround to enable us to still use `BMonthEnd` instead of providing codes to check and modify for Sunday and Saturday.

Here's the workaround code to enable `BMonthEnd` to behave similarly as `MonthEnd(n=0)`:

```
df['business_month_end'] = df['date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin() + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd()
```

Here, `MonthEnd(0)` is the same as `MonthEnd(n=0)` while `MonthEnd()` and `BMonthEnd()` without passing parameter is the same as passing `n=1` (the default).

The mechanism is that we borrow the feature of `MonthEnd(n=0)` to keep on anchor even on anchor point and get the month-begin of that date (should be the first date within the same month) and then apply the `BMonthEnd` function to let it gets us the last business date of the same month (with adjustments if dates fall on Sunday & Saturday).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df['month_end'] = df.date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0)
df.loc[df.index.day_name()=='Sunday', 'month_end'] -= pd.DateOffset(days=2)
df.loc[df.index.day_name()=='Saturday', 'month_end'] -= pd.DateOffset(days=1)
```

Note that if you are interested in the last business day of the month you could simply do:

```
df['month_end'] = df.date + pd.offsets.BusinessMonthEnd(n=0)
```